# How can I connect the Primary Key, Foreign Key and Alternative Key all together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I downloaded this database (it inlcudes the schema): https://wyobiz.wy.gov/business/database.aspx

I want to connect the entire database to basically one table.
So far I have this:

```
/*Table structure for table `filing` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `filing`;

CREATE TABLE `filing` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FILING_ID` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_TYPE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_SUBTYPE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORD_DESIGN_TYPE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DURATION_TERM_TYPE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SUB_STATUS` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STANDING_TAX` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STANDING_RA` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STANDING_OTHER` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PURPOSE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `APPLICANT_TYPE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_NUM` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_NAME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OLD_NAME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FICTITIOUS_NAME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOMESTIC_YN` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DELAYED_EFFECTIVE_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXPIRATION_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INACTIVE_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RA_RESIGN_CERT_LETTER_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONVERTED_YN` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONVERTED_FROM` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONVERTED_FROM_NAME` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONVERTED_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISSUE_ON_RECORD_YN` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSFERRED_TO` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSFERRED_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORMATION_LOCALE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTINUED_FROM_LOCALE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOMESTICATED_FROM_LOCALE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORM_HOME_JURIS_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMON_SHARES` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMON_PAR_VALUE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREFERRED_SHARES` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREFERRED_PAR_VALUE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDITIONAL_STOCK_YN` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_ADDR1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_ADDR2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_ADDR3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_CITY` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_STATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_POSTAL_CODE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRINCIPLE_COUNTRY` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_ADDR1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_ADDR2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_ADDR3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_CITY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_STATE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_POSTAL_CODE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAIL_COUNTRY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATE_OF_ORG` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORG_DATE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REG_US_OFFICE_YN` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REG_US_DATE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REG_US_SERIAL_NUM` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REG_US_STATUS` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REG_US_APP_REFUSED_YN` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_USED_ANYWHERE_DATE` blob,
  `FIRST_USED_WYO_DATE` blob,
  `AR_EXEMPT_YN` blob,
  `TRADEMARK_KEYWORDS` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `filing` */

/*Table structure for table `filing_annual_report` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `filing_annual_report`;

CREATE TABLE `filing_annual_report` (
  `FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FILING_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ANNUAL_REPORT_NUM` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_YEAR` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILING_DATE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LICENSE_TAX_AMT` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `filing_annual_report` */

/*Table structure for table `party` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `party`;

CREATE TABLE `party` (
  `PARTY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PARTY_TYPE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_ID` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOURCE_TYPE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORG_NAME` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MIDDLE_NAME` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDIVIDUAL_TITLE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDR1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDR2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDR3` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSTAL_CODE` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PARTY_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `party` */
```

Comment: Check  your tag. This is MySql syntax, not sql-server-2008.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have imported the CSV Data into your DB, the schema seems to indicate PARTY is linked to FILING using the FK PARTY.SOURCE_ID and FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT is linked to FILING using the FK FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT.FILING_ID.

The query to get all entries in one table would be

```
select * from FILING f
join PARTY p on p.SOURCE_ID=f.FILING_ID
join FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT a on a.FILING_ID=f.FILING_ID
```

To speed up the query build indexes before running the query:

```
create index ff on FILING(filing_id);
create index pf on PARTY(source_id);
create index af on FILING_ANNUAL_REPORT(filing_id);
```